# How to stub ApplicationController method in request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I am needing to stub the response of a `current_user` method in an Rspec/capybara request spec. The method is defined in `ApplicationController` and is using helper_method. The method should simply return a user id. Within the test, I'd like this method to return the same user id each time.

Alternatively, I could fix my problem by setting `session[:user_id]` in the spec (which is what `current_user` returns)... but that doesn't seem to work either.

Are either of these possible?

Edit:

Here is what I've got (it is not working. It just runs the normal current_user method).

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Login" do

   before(:each) do
     ApplicationController.stub(:current_user).and_return(User.first)
   end

  it "logs in" do
    visit '/'
    page.should have_content("Hey there user!")
  end

end
```

Also not working:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Login" do

  before(:each) do
    @mock_controller = mock("ApplicationController") 
    @mock_controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(User.first)
  end

  it "logs in" do
    visit '/'
    page.should have_content("Hey there user!")
  end

end
```

Comment: Is `current_user` a class method? I guess no.  So instead of `ApplicationController.stub(:current_user)` you may need `ApplicationController.any_instance.stub(:current_user)`.

Answer (score 64):

skalee  seems to have provided the correct answer in the comment.

If the method you're trying to stub is an instance method (most likely) and not a class method then you need use:

`ApplicationController.any_instance.stub(:current_user)`

Comment: This still works for Rspec 3 but gives deprecation warning. This is the new syntax: `allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:current_user).and_return(your_test_user)`

Comment: Love this quote - "Using this feature is often a design smell" - from the [Rspec docs](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks).

Answer (score 15):

Here are a couple of examples of the basic form.

```
controller.stub(:action_name).and_raise([some error])
controller.stub(:action_name).and_return([some value])
```

In your particular case, I believe the proper form would be:

```
controller.stub(:current_user).and_return([your user object/id])
```

Here's a full working example from a project I work on:

```
describe PortalsController do

  it "if an ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken is raised the user should be redirected to login" do
    controller.stub(:index).and_raise(ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)
    get :index
    flash[:notice].should eql("Your session has expired.")
    response.should redirect_to(portals_path)
  end

end
```

To explain my full example, basically what this does is verify that, when an `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error is raised anywhere in the app, that a flash message appears, and the user is redirected to the `portals_controller#index` action. You can use these forms to stub out and return specific values, test an instance of a given error being raised, etc. There are several `.stub(:action_name).and_[do_something_interesting]()` methods available to you.

---

**Update** (after you added your code): per my comment, change your code so it reads:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Login" do

   before(:each) do
      @mock_controller = mock("ApplicationController") 
      @mock_controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(User.first)
   end

  it "logs in" do
    visit '/'
    page.should have_content("Hey there user!")
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that looks like a controller spec, as opposed to a request spec. I am pretty new to testing, so I could be wrong :)

Comment: Stub just acts as a replacer for any method defined on any class. In the example you gave, it is a method `current_user` defined on `ApplicationController`, correct? The same basic form should work, unless I'm misunderstanding your question. Can you post the best form of the test you've written, even if it's not working?

Comment: So, I was assuming that your test was inside a spec that starts with `describe ApplicationController`, so my bad there. If that's not the case, then you should still be able to do `ApplicationController.stub(:current_user).and_return([your user object/id])`

Comment: Or maybe declare a mock object first for the ApplicationController, and then define the stub on that: `mock_controller = mock("ApplicationController")` followed by `mock_controller.stub(:current_user).and_return([your user object/id])` - http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/

Comment: I tried those both (see the code I added above). Still no luck. The original `current_user` method still gets called.

Comment: The code you posted declares `mock_controller` as a local variable (which is only accessible from within the `before` method). Change the declaration to `@mock_controller ...`

Comment: Dang. Still not working :(   I edited the code above to reflect your suggestion. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: I am having the exact same problem in request specs and cannot figure it out!!

Comment: Are you wrapping your def current_user code in if cookies[:auth_token] or something similar, by chance? Because that's what mine was doing so it still returned nil(false), so I stubbed User.find_by_auth_token! and returned my mock user, removed the if cookies[:auth_token] line, and now I'm good. It should still come back nil if there is no auth_token in the visitors' cookie

Comment: Bleh: you know what? That doesn't work when cookies[:auth_token] is not present since User.find_by_auth_token! raises an error for user not found... I wish we could just stub :current_user!! :P

Comment: I'm trying to do something even more basic in a request spec: `WidgetController.stub(:index)` followed by `get :index`. My actual WidgetController index method gets called every time; it's like the stub isn't there. I tried both forms listed in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me and gives me a `@current_user` variable to use in tests.

I have a helper that looks like this:

```
def bypass_authentication
  current_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

  ApplicationController.send(:alias_method, :old_current_user, :current_user)
  ApplicationController.send(:define_method, :current_user) do 
    current_user
  end
  @current_user = current_user
end

def restore_authentication
  ApplicationController.send(:alias_method, :current_user, :old_current_user)
end
```

And then in my request specs, I call:

```
before(:each){bypass_authentication}
after(:each){restore_authentication}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Rspec 3+ the new api is:

For a controller test, nice and short:

```
allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(@user)
```

Or for all instances of ApplicationController:

```
allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:current_user).and_return(@user)
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who happens to need to stub an application controller method that sets an ivar (and was stymied by endless wanking about why you shouldn't do that) here's a way that works, with the flavour of Rspec circa October 2013.

```
before(:each) do
  campaign = Campaign.create!
  ApplicationController.any_instance.stub(:load_campaign_singleton)
  controller.instance_eval{@campaign = campaign}
  @campaign = campaign
end
```

it stubs the method to do nothing, and sets the ivar on rspec's controller instance, and makes it available to the test as @campaign.

Comment: Tool late to end the endless wanking but just in the nick of time to keep me from throwing my computer out the window. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

None of the provided responses worked for me. As in @matt-fordam's original post, I have a request spec, not a controller spec. The test just renders the view without launching a controller.

I resolved this by stubbing the method on the view as described in this [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14085758/201911)

```
view.stub(:current_user).and_return(etc)
```