# rspec view stubs and partials

Tags: rspec, view, partials, stubs

I'm testing a view with RSpec (2.12 on Rails 3.2.8). I'm using CanCan to conditionally display certain elements on a page. This requires a controller method 'current_user'. In some of my specs I've been able to stub out current_user, eg.
    controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(etc) 
or 
    view.stub.etc .

This works for some of my specs. But I've got a couple where it's not working and I don't understand why.

The two specs where it's not working test a view, which calls down into a partial, and inside the partial I access 'current_user' as a method. The error is

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user'
```

So I guess my question is how to stub methods correctly so that they can be accessed down inside partials.

How should it be done?

Answer (score 11):

A controller stub won't work because you're not testing a controller, you're testing a view. Just use a view stub instead:

```
view.stub(:current_user).and_return(etc)
```

This should work in a partial as well as in a view.

See: [passing view spec that stubs a helper method](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-7/docs/view-specs/view-spec#passing-view-spec-that-stubs-a-helper-method)

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but it didn't work, so I tried controller.stub and that didn't work either. So now I'm mystified. I can get view.stub(etc) to work if and only if it's a one level view that's being tested. If the view calls a partial, then the method isn't available in the partial.

Comment: Ah! I worked it out, I need to have both view.stub(:current_user) and controller.stub(:current_user). Any references to current_user in the view, go through to the view.stub, and any references to current_user inside the CanCan ability class go through to controller.stub