# RSpec: Stub controller method in request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, doorkeeper

I'm writing an [RSpec request spec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec), which looks roughly like (somewhat shortened for brevity):

```
describe 'Items', type: :request do
  describe 'GET /items' do
    before do
      allow_any_instance_of(ItemsController).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
      get '/items'
      @parsed_body = JSON.parse(response.body)
    end

    it 'includes all of the items' do
      expect(@parsed_body).to include(item_1)
      expect(@parsed_body).to include(item_2)
    end
  end
end
```

The controller looks like:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!
  def index
    render(json: current_user.items)
  end
end
```

As you can see, I'm trying to stub doorkeeper's `current_user` method.

The tests currently pass and the controller works as expected. My question is about the line:

```
allow_any_instance_of(ItemsController).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
```

I wrote this line based on the answers in [How to stub ApplicationController method in request spec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7448974/1445366), and it works. However, [the RSpec docs call it a "code smell"](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance) and `rubocop-rspec` complains, "`RSpec/AnyInstance: Avoid stubbing using allow_any_instance_of`".

One alternative would be to get a reference to the controller and use `instance_double()`, but I'm not sure how to get a reference to the controller from a request spec.

How should I write this test avoid code smells / legacy testing approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to be on vacation.

I think the right way is to avoid stubbing as much as you can in a request spec, doorkeeper needs a token to authorize so I'd do something like:

```
describe 'Items', type: :request do
  describe 'GET /items' do
    let(:application) { FactoryBot.create :oauth_application }
    let(:user)        { FactoryBot.create :user }
    let(:token)       { FactoryBot.create :access_token, application: application, resource_owner_id: user.id }
    before do
      get '/items', access_token: token.token
      @parsed_body = JSON.parse(response.body)
    end

    it 'includes all of the items' do
      expect(@parsed_body).to include(item_1)
      expect(@parsed_body).to include(item_2)
    end
  end
end
```

Here are [some examples](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-provider-app/tree/master/spec/factories) of what those factories might look like.

Lastly, nice SO points!

Comment:  this got me a lot closer, thanks! I'm still having trouble generating a valid access token though. I'll post a separate question about that.

Comment: Here's my followup question if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60764500/1445366

Answer (score 1):

have you thought not to mock `current_user` at all?

if you write a test helper to sign in a `user` before your request spec,  `current_user` will be populate automatically as if it was a real user. The code would look like this:

```rb
before do
  sign_in user
  get '/items'
  @parsed_body = JSON.parse(response.body)
end
```

if you are using `devise` gem for authentication it has a nice written wiki page about that [here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-sign-in-and-out-a-user-in-Request-type-specs-(specs-tagged-with-type:-:request)).

This approach is also recommended [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23386#issuecomment-192954569) by @dhh

Comment: Thanks, the links you gave were really helpful. Looks like `sign_in` won't work in my case though since I am using doorkeeper with access tokens.