# Invalid access_token when using RSpec request specs to authorize a request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, doorkeeper

I'm trying to test `CredentialsController`, which works fine in production, using RSpec request specs.

## Code

### Controller

```
class CredentialsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!
  def me
    render json: current_user
  end
end
```

(`GET /me` routes to `CredentialsController#me`.)

### Request Specs

```
describe 'Credentials', type: :request do
  context 'unauthorized' do
    it "should 401" do
      get '/me'
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:unauthorized)
    end
  end

  context 'authorized' do
    let!(:application) { FactoryBot.create(:application) }
    let!(:user)        { FactoryBot.create(:user) }
    let!(:token)       { FactoryBot.create(:access_token, application: application, resource_owner_id: user.id) }

    it 'succeeds' do
      get '/me', params: {}, headers: {access_token: token.token}
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
  end
end
```

The unauthorized test passes, but the authorized test fails:

> expected `#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x00007fd339411248 @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x00007fd339410438>, @mo..., @method=nil, @request_method=nil, @remote_ip=nil, @original_fullpath=nil, @fullpath=nil, @ip=nil>>.successful?` to return true, got false

The headers indicate a problem with the token:

```
0> response.headers['WWW-Authenticate']
=> "Bearer realm=\"Doorkeeper\", error=\"invalid_token\", error_description=\"The access token is invalid\""
```

`token` looks okay to me, though:

```
0> token
=> #<Doorkeeper::AccessToken id: 7, resource_owner_id: 8, application_id: 7, token: "mnJh2wJeEEDe0G-ukNIZ6oupKQ7StxJqKPssjZTWeAk", refresh_token: nil, expires_in: 7200, revoked_at: nil, created_at: "2020-03-19 20:17:26", scopes: "public", previous_refresh_token: "">

0> token.acceptable?(Doorkeeper.config.default_scopes)
=> true
```

### Factories

#### Access Token

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :access_token, class: "Doorkeeper::AccessToken" do
    application
    expires_in { 2.hours }
    scopes { "public" }
  end
end
```

#### Application

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :application, class: "Doorkeeper::Application" do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Project #{n}" }
    sequence(:redirect_uri)  { |n| "https://example#{n}.com" }
  end
end
```

#### User

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "email#{n}@example.com" }
    password { "test123" }
    password_confirmation { "test123" }
  end
end
```

## Questions

- Why am I getting `invalid_token` on this request?
- Do my Doorkeeper factories look correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was passing the token wrong. Instead of:

```
get '/me', params: {}, headers: {access_token: token.token}
```

I had to use:

```
get '/me', params: {}, headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.token}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check your **Access Token** factory's scopes, It should be same as initializer's `default_scopes`

e.g.

**config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb**

```
default_scopes :read
```

Below, your **Access Token** factory's scopes should be

```
factory :access_token, class: "Doorkeeper::AccessToken" do
  sequence(:resource_owner_id) { |n| n }
  application
  expires_in { 2.hours }
  scopes { "read" }
end
```

Additionally, if you encountered response status: 406 while `get '/me'....`

It means that the requested format (by default HTML) is not supported. Instead of '.json' you can also send Accept="application/json" in the HTTP header.

```
get '/me', params: {}, headers: { 
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.token, 
  'Accept': 'application/json'}
```

I resolved my problem with this solution, maybe you can try it.